# How to expand variables after entering custom define that wraps foreach?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have many very similar `$(foreach..)` loops in a makefile that work like in the `target_old` target below:

```
define NL


endef
extras=some/path/
vars=a b c

all: target_old target_new

target_old:
        # foreach and some multiple evals inside and some multiple commands inside
        $(foreach var, ${vars}, \
                $(eval extra := ${extras}${var}) \
                @echo var is ${var} and extras is ${extra}$(NL) \
        )


# my try to wrap it in a function
define foreach_vars
        $(foreach var, ${vars},
                $(eval extra := ${extras}${var}) \
                $1$(NL) \
        )
endef

target_new:
        @echo this is wrong:
        $(call foreach_vars, \
                @echo var is ${var} and extras is ${extra} \
        )
```

I have many multiple such `foreach` loops with all the same `eval`s inside the `foreach`. So I wanted to wrap the `foreach` loop with the `eval`s inside my own function in `foreach_vars`. So I don't have to `$(eval extra := ${extras}${var})` inside each `foreach` call. I created `target_new` target to test it. I would want the output from both targets to be the same, `make target_old` prints:

```
$ make target_old
var is a and extras is some/path/a
var is b and extras is some/path/b
var is c and extras is some/path/c
```

However `target_new` doesn't pick the `${var}` from inside the loop, and `${var}` just expands to nothing:

```
$ make target_new
this is wrong:
var is and extras is
var is and extras is
var is and extras is
```

I guess this is because the expansion happens before entering the `$(call...)`. Is there any method I can use to "defer" the expansion of arguments inside the `$(call...)` call until inside `foreach` inside my function? Is is possible to write a custom foreach-like macro in make? Is there just other method used to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your problem comes from the expansion(s) that do not happen when you would like and in the order you would like.

Your use of make is quite unusual because you are using make constructs (`foreach`, `eval`, `call`...) in recipes that are normally plain shell. I guess you have a very good reason but wouldn't it be much easier if you were separating the make world and the shell world? Like in the following, for instance:

```
extras := some/path/
vars   := a b c

target_old:
    @for var in $(vars); do \
       extra=$(extras)$${var}; \
       echo var is $${var} and extra is $${extra}; \
     done
```

It uses make variables (`vars`, `extras`) and shell variables (`extra`, `var`). The recipe is plain shell. Note the `$$` used to escape the first expansion by make such that the shell expansion `${xxx}` is done by the shell. Note also the line continuations (`\`) that form a single line recipe, despite the look. As each line of a make recipe is executed by a separate shell, this is needed to pass shell variables between commands of the shell script.

If you wish, you can also wrap the shell for loop in a make recursively expanded variable:

```
for = for var in $(vars); do $(1); done

target_new:
    @$(call for,extra=$(extras)$${var}; echo var is $${var} and extra is $${extra})
```

Comment: This formulation hides the exit code of the command from _make_

Comment: Which formulation? The last one? Did you give it a try, e.g. by adding `; exit 1` at the end of the `call` parameter? You should.

Comment: `exit 1` is an exception that escapes the running shell. You need to simulate a failing command with `(exit 1)`: `$(call for,extra=$(extras)$${var}; echo var is $${var} and extra is $${extra}; (exit 22))` say

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, you are right, make does not fail if the exit status of the last command of the shell is not 0. Not sure I understand why. But if this is a problem there are probably several ways to fix it, like, for instance, adding `; exit $$?` at the end of the `for` definition. Or adding ` || exit $$?` at the end of the `call` parameter.

Comment: `man bash` says _The return status is the  exit  status  of the  last command that executes_. `set -e` is often useful

Answer (score 1):

`${var}` gets immediately expanded, so it needs to be escaped as `$${var}`. This itself does not fix the issue, since now `$1` contains a literal `${var}`, which does NOT get expanded within `foreach`. I would make a simple `subst` though to get it fixed, e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
define NL


endef
extras=some/path/
vars=a b c

define foreach_vars
        $(foreach var, ${vars},
                $(eval extra := ${extras}${var}) \
                $(subst $$(var),$(var), \
                $(subst $$(extra),$(extra), \
                $(1))) \
                $(NL) \
        )
endef

target_new:
        $(call foreach_vars, \
                @echo var is $$(var) and extras is $$(extra) \
        )
```

Output:

```
$ make target_new
var is a and extras is some/path/a
var is b and extras is some/path/b
var is c and extras is some/path/c
```

Answer (score 1):

When *make* comes to build *target_new* (like when you type `make target_new` for instance):

- It expands the whole recipe
  **Important:** The recipe is expanded *before* firing up the shell
- For each line of the resulting expansion, it passes one at a time to a fresh invocation of the shell

It's worth showing the expansion *make* does in painful detail. We have as the recipe:

```
@echo this is wrong:
$(call foreach_vars, \
    @echo var is ${var} and extras is ${extra} \
)
```

- First off, `${var}` becomes empty, as is `${extra}`
- *make* is left with `$(call foreach_vars, @echo var is  and extras is  )`. Now for the *call*:

  - `1` is set to `@echo var is  and extras is`
  - *make* expands `$(foreach var, ${vars}, $(eval extra := ${extras}${var})   $1$(NL) )`
  - `${vars}` is `a b c`

    - First iteration:

      - `var` is set to `a`
      - *Make* evals `extra := some/path/a`
      - The expansion of the *eval* is empty however, and we are left with `$1$(NL)` (modulo some whitespace), leaving `@echo var is  and extras is`
    - Second iteration: `${extra}` becomes `some/path/b`, and we are again left with `@echo var is  and extras is`
    - Last iteration: `${extra}` becomes `some/path/c`, and we are again left with `@echo var is  and extras is`

The final recipe then:

```
@echo this is wrong:
@echo var is  and extras is
@echo var is  and extras is
@echo var is  and extras is
```

which produces the output you described.

So how do we avoid the early expansion of parameters?
Once nice solution is to stick the command-line you want into a variable,
and pass the name of that variable instead.

```
define foreach_vars # 1: variable containing command-line
    $(foreach var,${vars},
            $(eval extra := ${extras}${var}) \
            ${$1}$(NL) \
    )
endef

cmds<target_new> = @echo var is ${var} and extras is ${extra}

target_new:
    @echo this is right:
    $(call foreach_vars,cmds<$@>)
```

Why mangle the variable name with the name of the target? Lookup tables are nice, and you may find many targets ending up with the same recipe.

```
cmds<target_new> = @echo var is ${var} and extras is ${extra}
cmds<target_beta> = ${MAKE} ${var}-${extra}
cmds<target_release> = script ${var} | eat ${extra}

target_new target_beta target_release:
    $(call foreach_vars,cmds<$@>)
```

etc.

Comment: Nice! Yes, yes, I thought about it. Never could implement it properly. I think I'll try to go with not splitting the variable definition into a separate line, just in one line with `$(eval )`. Like such: `$(eval command = @echo var is ${var} and extras is ${extra})$(call foreach_vars, command)`.

Comment: No reason to put them on the same line. Just write in the most readable way you can. Remember, line breaks are really only important once the expansion has finished, as they delineate separate shell commands.